# Issues understanding mapMulti

Tags: java, stream, mapmulti

I'm fairly when it comes to Java, and I've decided to dig a little into the implementations and uses of the API, especially the Stream API.

I've made an implementation after thinking I got it right, and it worked. However I realized something that bugged me out.

The mapMulti function takes in parameter a `BiConsumer` :

```java
    default <R> Stream<R> mapMulti(BiConsumer<? super T, ? super Consumer<R>> mapper) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(mapper);
        return flatMap(e -> {
            SpinedBuffer<R> buffer = new SpinedBuffer<>();
            mapper.accept(e, buffer);
            return StreamSupport.stream(buffer.spliterator(), false);
        });
    }
```

Then I wanted to benchmark the mapMulti function by passing it the accept function of my Element class (That's why i discard the value of `s`, and the ExecutionPlan simply has values to benchmark with JMH

```java
    public void mapMultiTest(ExecutionPlan exec){
        Stream<Integer> s = exec.elts.stream().mapMulti(Element::accept);
    }
```

Here is the Element class, which simply decomposes an int into prime factors, and calls forEach on the consumer.

```java
public record Element(int value) {

    public void accept(Consumer<Integer> consumer) {
        decomp().forEach(consumer);
    }

    public ArrayList<Integer> decomp() {
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        int value = this.value;

        while (!isPrime(value)) {
            int prime = 2;
            while (!isPrime(prime) || value % prime != 0)
                prime++;
            list.add(prime);
            value /= prime;
        }
        list.add(value);
        return list;
    }

    private boolean isPrime(int num) {
        if (num <= 1) {
            return false;
        }
        for (int i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(num); i++) {
            if (num % i == 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

My issue is : Why is my Element::accept (which is theorically the `mapper` arg) considered as valid when it is not of the type BiConsumer, and takes only one argument, eventhough when it is called inside mapMulti, it takes the element and buffer argument.

I may totally be missing something obvious or having a wrong understanding of those kind of functions, but I'm having some troubles understanding `BiConsumer, Consumer, Functions, BiFunctions` etc.

Thanks in advance, and I hope I'll understand this kind of subjects that I find very interesting, especially the way all those API are developped.

Comment: You miss one important point: `Element.accept()` is an instance method. To call it, you need two objects: an `Element` instance and a `Consumer<Integer> consumer`. Method references are smart enough to detect this as a `BiConsumer<Element, Consumer<Integer> consumer`

Comment: Woah, so that's why ! Thanks a lot i didn't know that :) !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as **@Thomas Kläger** pointed out in the comments

> Element.accept() is an instance method. To call it, you need two
> objects: an Element instance and a Consumer consumer. Method
> references are smart enough to detect this as a BiConsumer<Element,
> Consumer consumer

So

```java
elts.stream().<Integer>mapMulti((elt,cons)->{
            elt.accept(cons);
        })
```

And

```java
elts.stream().<Integer>mapMulti(Element::accept)
```

Are the same thing

**Thanks a lot !**